# How to make Bootstrap Tab return to the first tab after login

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have a burning question: I used a jquery script to make my bootstrap tab to remain on the same tab after page reload. My question is this: after filling my forms from the first tab to the last tab, after submitting, when i log out and relogin again, it still remains on the last tab before i logged out. What do i do to ensure it goes back to the first tab whenever i login again?
Find my form below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Keep Selected Bootstrap Tab Active on Page Refresh</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
    });
    var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
    if(activeTab){
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="m-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#sectionA" class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab">Section A</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#sectionB" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Section B</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#sectionC" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Section C</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade show active">
                <h3>Section A</h3>
                <p>Aliquip placeat salvia cillum iphone...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Section B</h3>
                <p>Vestibulum nec erat eu nulla rhoncus fringilla...</p>
            </div>
            <div id="sectionC" class="tab-pane fade">
                <h3>Section C</h3>
                <p>Nullam hendrerit justo non leo aliquet...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to clear `localStorage` when logout like `localStorage.clear();`

Comment: Many thanks @SimoneRossaini. Where do i need to insert the 'localStorage.clear( );

Comment: On your logout system/script.

Comment: Thank you. @SimoneRossaini. I am making use of asp.net login control. Any clue on how to implement it there?

Comment: I personally don't use ASP however you could do, when the user clicks on the logout button run `localStorage.clear();`

Comment: Thank you  protected void LoginStatus2_LoggedOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        localStorage.clear();
    }  I have done but it is displaying the error message: "the name localStorage does not exist in the current context"